# Float precision when dealing with logarithms in musical pitch calculations

Tags: python, floating-accuracy, logarithm, pitch

I'm writing a simple program to determine the difference between two musical pitches in cents; one cent is equal to 1/100th of a semitone. Dealing in cents is preferable for comparing musical pitches because the frequency scale is logarithmic, not linear. In theory, this is an easy calculation: the formula for determining the number of cents between two frequencies is:

```
1200 * log2(pitch_a / pitch_b)
```

I've written a small piece of code to automate this process:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def cent_difference(pitch_a, pitch_b)
     cents = 1200 * np.abs(math.log2(pitch_a / pitch_b))
     return cents
```

This works perfectly when I give the program octaves:

```
In [28]: cent_difference(880, 440)
Out[28]: 1200.0
```

...but misses the mark by about two cents on a perfect fifth:

```
In [29]: cent_difference(660, 440)
Out[29]: 701.9550008653875
```

...and keeps getting worse as I go, missing by about 14 cents on a major third:

```
In [30]: cent_difference(550, 440)
Out[30]: 386.31371386483477
```

Is this all float precision nonsense? Why does the perfect 5th example overestimate the cents, but the major third example underestimate the cents? What's going on here?

Much obliged for any help!

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` here???

Comment: Anyway, yeah, don't expect exact values using floating point numbers. Use `decimal.Decimal` objects instead. Although, if you *actually* need `numpy`, that might be a problem

Comment: Floating point numbers cannot accurately represent real numbers. No digital representation of a real number can every be infinitely precise, but even reasonably precise is hard with standard floats. You can use a higher precision data type (and the operations defined upon them) or use an algorithm that doesn't dip too deep into the pool and stays sufficiently precise for your needs.

Comment: @Grismar to be pedantic, floating point numbers *can* accurately represent *some* numbers, particularly, those numbers representable in base 2 for a given size

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and to be equally pedantic, nowhere did I say no real number can be represented precisely. *Obviously* "0" is a counter-example to that silly statement. Your response also ignore the fact there are literally infinitely more reals that cannot be represented than there are ones that can - they are a dwindling fraction, so your comment is rather pointless.

Comment: @Grismar my point was just to clarify the the actual problem -- the reason floating point numbers give us problems is because their representation is in base-2, "binary", and they are limited in size, that is all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Re “the actual problem”: As we see in the answers, floating-point rounding is not the actual problem here. Please do not assume that just because some question involves floating-point arithmetic that floating-point rounding is the problem. It should not be a knee-jerk comment to any floating-point question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having *isn't* about the accuracy of Python's `float` type, but about the discrepancy between [equal temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament) and [just intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_intonation) in music.

```
>>> cent_difference(660, 440)
701.9550008653874
```

This is assuming that a P5 interval represents a frequency ratio of 3/2.  But in 12-ET, it doesn't: It has a ratio of 2<sup>7/12</sup> ≈ 1.4983070768766815.  With the proper ET value for the higher note, you do get the expected 700.

```
>>> cent_difference(659.2551138257398, 440)
700.0
```

Comment: Ah nice, interesting - did not realise that, thanks :)

Comment: The results are identical using `abs` or `np.abs` - I assume OP tried `np.abs` hoping for better accuracy. But your answer is the correct one here - even `print(1200 * abs(math.log2(660 / 440)))` is perfectly accurate.

Comment: I feel intensely stupid that I didn't realize this was the problem, but that's what you get when you code late at night! I'm fairly new to Python, so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

> What's going on here?

[You're inputting frequency intervals in just intonation and expecting results in equal temperament.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Comparison_with_just_intonation).

If you feed the equal-tempered major third frequency ratio of 2^(4/12) into your formula, you indeed get a result of 400 cents (within floating point accuracy, as explained by the other answers and comments).

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that floating point numbers use a set number of bits to represent any of the real numbers. Since there's infinitely many of those and only 2**32 values for a 32-bit float (at best), you can see how there will effectively be infinitely many reals that will have to be approximated. And if you keep computing with those approximations, errors occur.

You don't have to use large or long numbers to run into one either. My favourite:

```
>>> .1 + .1 + .1
0.30000000000000004
```

You can use more accurate types, which use better representations at the cost of some speed (and sometimes use operations that are slower but less likely to introduce errors).

For example `Decimal`, but make sure you use integers to define them:

```
>>> .1 + .1 + .1
0.30000000000000004
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(.1) + Decimal(.1) + Decimal(.1)
Decimal('0.3000000000000000166533453694')
>>> Decimal (1)/Decimal(10) + Decimal(1)/Decimal(10) + Decimal(1)/Decimal(10)
Decimal('0.3')
```

The best solution, if one exists for your problem, is to avoid floating point math altogether.

By the way, here's your problem using `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context


def cent_difference(pitch_a, pitch_b, ctx):
    ratio = ctx.divide(pitch_a, pitch_b)
    cents = Decimal(1200) * ctx.copy_abs(ratio.ln(ctx) / Decimal(2).ln(ctx))
    return cents


ctx = Context(prec=20)
print(cent_difference(Decimal(880), Decimal(440), ctx))
print(cent_difference(Decimal(660), Decimal(440), ctx))
```

Result:

```
1200
701.95500086538741774000
```

So, not that different. I'm not sure what result you expected on the second one there. If you pop over to Wolfram Alpha and task it with `1200 * log2(660 / 440)`, there seems to be no clean way to write this without the log still in there - precision will be lost for any representation in digits of an irrational number.

Comment: Or strings, which might be easier in this case, `Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1")`

Comment: Indeed  - depending on the complexity of the operation required, one or the other may be quicker, but strings are certainly more readable, and I agree that may matter more. Especially since code already gets harder to read with the introduction of `Decimal`

Comment: Note that while `Decimal` does allow higher precision than a standard `float`, it only gives *exact* representation for fractions with a power of 10 in the denominator.  And of course, it can't give exact answers to non-algebraic functions like `log`, `exp`, or `sin`.

Comment: @dan4 - true, I added an example of OP's case to show `Decimal` is of limited (if any) use here.

Comment: You should not just assume that because a calculation with a wrong answer uses floating-point, it is due to rounding in floating-point. That hypothesis should be tested, and it is fairly easy to see that the `float` format is sufficiently precise that `1200*abs(log2(a/b))` would not produce a difference of 2 out of 700.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I fully agree; I took OP's information for granted, but luckily dan04 already pointed out that the problem was the premise. I left my answer since I do think it shows how to solve OP's problem using Decimal, and since the question will lead more people with similar problems here, I think it would still be instructive.